# Creating a variable which indicates if a target date is between two dates, but there are several rows per case

Tags: r, date, variables, group-by

I am trying to create a new variable called **positive** which indicates that the **targ_date** is between a date range between **st_date** and **en_date**, but there are several rows per **ID**. I am trying to create something like the variable positive. For instance if between a date range, the target date is within, then that date range should be assigned a 1, otherwise a 0. Here is a code to reproduce what I need.

```
ID<-c("4674","4674","4674","4674","4674","4674","4674",   "25694","25694","25694","25694","25694","25694","25694", "92252","92252","92252","92252","92252") 

st_date<-c(NA,NA,"2022-05-09",NA,NA,"2013-07-01","2013-11-27", NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,"2011-04-14","2011-08-04", NA,NA,"2015-08-07","2017-08-18",NA) 

en_date<-c(NA,NA,"2022-06-10",NA,NA,"2013-08-01","2013-12-27", NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,"2011-06-13","2011-08-15", NA,NA,"2015-09-09","2017-09-18",NA) 

targ_date<-c("2022-05-15","2013-05-01",NA,NA,NA,"2013-06-30",NA, NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,"2011-06-13","2011-07-15", NA,NA,"2015-08-20","2017-08-23",NA) 

positive<-c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,1,0, 0,0,1,0,0) 

data<-data.frame(ID,st_date,en_date,targ_date,positive)
```

I have tried:

```
ds <- ds %>% 
group_by(ID) %>% 
mutate( between_any = as.numeric(inrange(targ_date, st_date, en_date)) ) %>% 
ungroup()
```

but it does not do what I want.

Comment: How do you want to handle the situations where there are multiple date ranges for the same id or no date range but it has a target?

Comment: In cases where there are multiple date ranges per ID, if one contains a target date then that range should be marked as 1, otherwise, 0. If more than one date range from same ID contains more than one target date, then each of these date range should be marked as 1, otherwise 0. If there are IDs without date ranges, then, there will be 0 only. The idea is to mark as 1 each of the date ranges that contain a target date within each group of rows that share same ID. I hope this is more clear and thank you for the help.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying - see response, if that is not correct then just let me know what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

Revised answer to use a helper function that looks for a target date in the sequence of start and end dates for each id.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
data<-data.frame(ID,st_date,en_date,targ_date,positive)
data <- data %>% mutate(across(c(targ_date, en_date, st_date), ymd))
data <- split(data, data$ID)

FindMatch <- function(x) {
  targets <- unique(na.omit(x$targ_date))
  
  for(i in 1:length(x$ID)) {
    if(!is.na(x[i,]$st_date)) {
      x$Match[i] <- max(seq.Date(x[i,]$st_date, x[i,]$en_date,by= 1) %in% targets)
    }
    else {
      x$Match[i] <- 0
    }
  }
  return(x)
}

data <- lapply(data, FindMatch)
data <- do.call(rbind, data)
```

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that your solution indicates the **targ_date** that is between a **st_date** and **en_date** interval. But, what I want to indicate, is the time interval that contains at least one of the **targ_date**. Please see the dataset sample that I added at the beginning of this thread (variable named **positive**). Appreciate your help.

Comment: I think I understand, the above will return a match if any range contains any target date, that lines up with positive except for one element but the final id does seem to have two matches as aug 23 is within the range.